# how does Uipath's 'Write Range Workbook' work?

Tags: uipath

I want to know what is different between 'Write DataTable to Excel' and 'Write Range Workbook'.
As far as I know, 'Write DataTable to Excel' works as api and 'Write Range Workbook' modifies what's binary.
But I want to know exactly.

I looked for official documents, but I couldn't find out about them.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know...

Write DataTable to Excel:

- serializes the DataTable's data into a format that Excel can understand and creates a new Excel file or overwrites an existing one.
- The output is an Excel file with data structured according to the DataTable
- doesn't directly manipulate the Excel file's binary content; instead, it uses the Excel application's API to perform the operation.

Write Range Workbook:

- allows you to write data to specific cells or ranges within an Excel workbook.
- You specify the workbook, sheet, and range where you want to write data, and it updates the content in those specific cells or ranges.
- works with Excel files at a binary level, which means it modifies the actual file content directly.
- provides more control over the location and formatting of the data within the Excel file, but it requires you to manage Excel files in a more granular manner.

In conclusion, "Write DataTable to Excel" abstracts much of the technical complexity and offers a straightforward way to export data from a DataTable to an Excel file, while "Write Range Workbook" gives you finer control over where and how you write data in the Excel workbook but requires you to manage the Excel file at a lower, more technical level.

Comment: Hey @Rukkakka, if my answer helped you do you mind marking it as "accepted"?